# Cannot acess file Input/Output Error But can acess other files

Tags: data-recovery, corruption

I have copied a file from Android to Linux but it was unexpected that I got error for that specific file only and also cannot delete it but I can access other files without any problem. When using GUI I cannot even open that Volume but can access from terminal.

I just want to delete it in any way.

[image: ls -l screenshot]

Comment: So you're seeing that on a desktop Linux system, or on Android? If the desktop, which distribution are you using? (I'm not sure if matters, but anyway)

Comment: usually, on a single file, that might indicate an issue with the filesystem, or some odd filesystem that has different sorts of access controls than the usual ones. There's a bunch of questions on that https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=ls+code%3A%22-%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F%22 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=ls+question+marks

Comment: It looks like I have downloaded UTF16 but still I can't access my files nor even delete it.

Comment: Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, and the content will not show up in search engine results. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting. At that occasion, you can also replace any privacy-related information (hostnames/filenames) with generic, uncritical names (as long as the name is not the actual proclem).